# Unable to find the artifact from any repository org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.3

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to build an old project which runs with `apache-maven-2.2.1` and `Java 1.6`.

```
Project ID: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.3

from the specified remote repositories:
  codehaus-snapshot-repository (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  maven2-repository.dev.java.net (http://download.java.net/maven/2/),
  repo (file://C:\localrepo\lib)

 for project org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin
```

As you can see, I have downloaded the `maven-resources-plugin-2.3.jar` and put that into lib dir but why still it saying not found. How to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Upgrade your Maven versions and Java version... central is only available via https and not via http anymore ... Really using Maven 2.X? https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi download Maven 3.X and check if the build works...also upgrade all given plugins within your build.... don't try to download everything manually that will not work in the end (takes too much time)... also check the pom files if there are things given like `http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/` which does not exist anymore ... etc. like `http://download.java.net/maven/2/`....

Comment: If you like to target to JDK 6 you can use JDK8 or JDK11 to target (via --release option) to target to jdk 6... but as far as I know JDK11 the minimum is JDK 7... (but I'm not sure here) ...so try JDK8 at least...

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks. The plugins available here - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/